# pyqt4, function Mute / Un mute microphone and also speakers [PJSIP]

Tags: python, pyqt4, pjsip

## Hello friends and colleagues

**I am trying to make a function mute / un mute microphone and  also speakers  for my program softphone  on pyt4  and using library PJSIP**

**I found this in the code pjsip**

#### pjsip:

```
    def conf_set_tx_level(self, slot, level):
        """Adjust the signal level to be transmitted from the bridge to 
        the specified port by making it louder or quieter.

        Keyword arguments:
        slot        -- integer to identify the conference slot number.
        level       -- Signal level adjustment. Value 1.0 means no level
                       adjustment, while value 0 means to mute the port.
        """
        lck = self.auto_lock()
        err = _pjsua.conf_set_tx_level(slot, level)
        self._err_check("conf_set_tx_level()", self, err)

    def conf_set_rx_level(self, slot, level):
        """Adjust the signal level to be received from the specified port
        (to the bridge) by making it louder or quieter.

        Keyword arguments:
        slot        -- integer to identify the conference slot number.
        level       -- Signal level adjustment. Value 1.0 means no level
                       adjustment, while value 0 means to mute the port.
        """
        lck = self.auto_lock()
        err = _pjsua.conf_set_rx_level(slot, level)
        self._err_check("conf_set_rx_level()", self, err)
```

**well I understand I need to send a parameter 0, but how to do?

And to return back work the sound device and microphone.

Maybe it """""pjsua_conf_adjust_tx_level(slot_number, 0 )"""""**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**himself answer :-)**

**in my case it was so**

```
        # call window

        ################ 
        self.MuteMic = False
        self.MuteSpeaker = False
        ################


        #btn signals
        self.connect(self.MuteUnmuteMicButton, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.MuteUnmuteMic)
        self.connect(self.MuteUnmuteSpeakerButton, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.MuteUnmuteSpeaker)




    def MuteUnmuteMic(self):
        try:
            if self.MuteMic:
                self.MuteMic = False
                self.parent().unmute_mic()
            else:
                self.MuteMic = True
                self.parent().mute_mic()

        except:
                debug ("ошибка при вызове функции включение или отключение микрофона (call Window).")

    def MuteUnmuteSpeaker(self):
        try:
            if self.MuteSpeaker:
                self.MuteSpeaker = False
                self.parent().unmute_speaker()
            else:
                self.MuteSpeaker = True
                self.parent().mute_speaker()

        except:
                debug ("ошибка при вызове функции включение или отключение микрофона (call Window).")

# other code


----------


# ----------------------core of the my app 
# ---import PJUA lib----

        def mute_mic(self):
            #this that you need in my case my app connected to pjua "self.lib"
            self.lib.conf_set_rx_level(0,0)

            debug ("вызвана функция выключение микрофона")
        def unmute_mic(self):
            self.lib.conf_set_rx_level(0,1)

        debug ("вызвана функция включение микрофона")
        def mute_speaker(self):         
            self.lib.conf_set_tx_level(0,0)

            debug ("вызвана функция выключение динамиков")
        def unmute_speaker(self):
            self.lib.conf_set_tx_level(0,1)

        debug ("вызвана функция включение динамиков")
```